# Why `int a=-1;printf('%lld',a)` output 4294967295?

Tags: c++

At [cplusplus official doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), I see `%lld` format expects long long int format, and when the type is not consistent, it will be promoted. And when -1 is promoted to long long int, it should be -1.So,why `int a=-1;printf("%lld",a)` output 4294967295?

Comment: The type 0xFFFFFFFF would only be a signed 32-bit integer type only on platforms where that type could hold *positive* values that large.

Comment: On a platform with 32-bit integers, `0xffffffff` has type `unsigned int`, and is not treated as `-1` when cast to a 64-bit signed integer type.

Comment: @TomKarzes, But even I use `int a=-1;printf("%lld",a)`, its output is still 4294967295

Comment: Using wrong type of argument for particular format specifier invokes an undefined behaviour (UB) If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined, this is in C++ standard

Comment: @jameslahm You have a type mismatch.  Your compiler should have warned about it (try increasing the warning level).  Change it to `(long long int) a` in the argument list and you should see a difference. For variadic functions, there is no prototype that gives the argument types, so you only get the standard promotions.  In particular, `int` remains `int` and `unsigned int` remains `unsigned int`.

Comment: Don't change your question after people have commented on it or, worse, answered it.  Only edit for clarification or minor corrections that are tangential to the problem.  In any case, my previous comment answers your new question.

Comment: @dgrandm, Thanks, but shouldn't it be a valid promotion when an `int` is promoted to `long long`?

Comment: @TomKarzes, Sorry for changing the question, I am still new to StackOverflow and I will pay attention next time. But I wonder shouldn't it be promoted to `long long` when format specifier is `%lld` and I pass in an `int`.

Comment: @jameslahm that does not happen, people have told you several times now but you keep ignoring.

Comment: @jameslahm No, it shouldn't, and I explained why already.  To repeat myself:  There is no prototype information for variadic arguments.  In this particular case, the format string has no effect on the argument promotions that follow it.  You are passing an `int` argument to a function that is trying to extract it as a `long long int` value.  The resulting behavior is unspecified.

Comment: @M.M, Thanks, get it.

Comment: @TomKarzes, Thank you very much, I understand the reason now.

Answer (score 1):

> when the type is not consistent, it will be promoted

This is not true. The argument must have type `long long int` otherwise the behaviour is undefined.  Also "cplusplus.com" is not "official doc", it is a privately run website.

The type of `0xffffffff` is implementation-defined. On common LLP64 implementations it will have type `long long` and give well-defined behaviour which is what you are seeing. On other implementations it might be `long` or even another type, so you could see anything.

Comment: Thanks, but I see "(if a different type is used, the proper type promotion or conversion is performed, if allowed)" in official doc. And I also try `short int a=-1;print("%d",a)`,its output is -1,showing it's promoted to int.

Comment: @jameslahm it's not official doc, that statement is wrong. The official doc is the ISO standard. The `short` example is also different (the integer promotions apply to arguments of variadic function, but this is not related to printf format string)

Comment: I kept on looking through C++ standard PDF and could not find anything like that. As far as my knowledge goes promotion only happens on function arguments type mismatch.

Comment: @dgrandm your "knowledge" is wrong, promotion is nothing to do with function arguments mismatch. Integral promotion is described in section [conv.prom] of the C++17 standard (and then other sections specify when integral promotion occurs as you can find by searching for use of that term)

Comment: @M.M, Thank you very much, I get it.

Comment: @M.M Thank you, I was wrong. Reading 7.6 "Integral promotions" ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing the expression `long test = 0x1000000000`. It is fairly clear that the programmer wants assign a value larger than what would fit in an `int` into the variable `test`. This is why values too large for the type of int are promoted to being a larger type. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal). In this case, your literal `0xffffffff` is too large to fit into a signed integer value, so it is promoted to be a long. This long is passed to printf, which prints the value it was passed.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I use `int a=-1;printf("%lld",a)`, its output is still 4294967295.

Comment: In this case the output is the same, but the cause is entirely different. The issue here is that the function `printf` can take any type of argument, and uses the format string to figure out what type of argument you are passing to it. In this case you are telling it "I am passing you a long" put actually passing in an int. You can fix this by explicitly casting your value to the correct type `printf("%lld", (long long int) a);`.


This behavior is why many C projects are compiled with the flags `-Wall -Werror` which will prevent you from making this mistake.

Comment: Thanks very much, I see that. But when the argument type is not consistent, shouldn't it be promoted to `long long`? Here I pass an int with the value of -1, then if promoted, it should be a `long long` with the value of -1, the output should be also -1.

Comment: There's no promotion involved here. "The type of a literal" does not have promotion as a step.

Comment: @M.M you are expecting `0xffffffff` to get *sign extended* to `0xffffffffffffffff`, and that is simply not what happens. If `0xffffffff` is larger than an `int` can hold, then the compiler uses the next largest type (`long` or `long long` depending on platform), and interprets `0xffffffff` as-is in that type, which would be `0x00000000ffffffff` which is indeed `4294967295` and not `-1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks ver much, I see that. I have changed my question.I wonder why `int a=-1;printf("%lld",a)`, its output is still 4294967295

Comment: @jameslahm that is **undefined behavior**. You are telling `printf()` that you promise to give it a `long long int` but then give it an `int` instead. The extra bits `printf()` expects don't exist, so they end up coming from random bits on the call stack next to the `int` and will be indeterminate, but *happen* to be zeros in your test case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Thanks very much,get it

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess you mistagged me there